# Julia what is the propper way to serve react frontend using electron from julia

Tags: reactjs, electron, julia

I am curently planning to rewrite a project of mine. I made in python and Pyside.

but :) I now realize that I have to learn a framewrok like react.js and electron for this.
the ui needs to have 2 pages one for some tableviews and 2 smaller plotly plots. and the second two large plots. with some toggle buttons at the top of earch plot.

well my question is how would I then serve the frontend from julia.

I have played abit with Blink and Interact. but I cant place plotlyJS plots in a layout like hbox/vbox then it throws stack overflow error. and when I use tabulator. and place a plot in earch tab it dossnent presver its width, it gets all compressed to the left.

All that said  I know I have alot to learn about the web frontend world. But I just need to find the right direction. so would rect.js, electron, julia. be a good choice ?
and if so how would you serve the app from julia Thank you!

Comment: When you write "how would you serve the app from Julia" do you mean that you want Julia to be a back end and make data available for your two web page UI, or did you mean you want Julia to be the front end for creation of the web pages?

Comment: Hey,  Julia as backend and electron/ react or vue, thats just what I would asume is the best option for this project :)

Comment: You can use HTTP.jl for the backend server services and JSON.jl or JSON2.jl to take and send JSON format data with Julia. The rest depends on what data you would be processing to get data for the graphs and table.

Comment: Have you seen: [ElectronDisplay.jl](https://www.queryverse.org/2019/02/13/electrondisplay/)?

Comment: Hey thx for the comments, yes I have seen Electron Display,  what I am unsure about is how would i combine lets say Electron.jl or Blink.jl with a react/Vue Frontend. lets say I build a simple ui using react how would i then use the build files.  or do I need to build the react app with electron